Turn on iCloud? prompt keeps popping up
My iCloud is activated, with nearly all features enabled except for iMessage.
I'm not sure if it's related, but there's this annoying pop-up that says "Turn on iCloud? Your network provider may charge for SMS messages used to activate iCloud" that keeps appearing. I keep dismissing it, just to be safe, in case my phone has been compromised or something. This is the first time I've encountered such a pop-up since using iPhones.
Anyone had this popup before?


If you out the phone in airplane mode and then restart can you use the phone without this pop up? I would do that and sign in to iCloud online or another device to check your account. Assuming you can access it, turn on WiFi only and take note how long it takes for that to pop up.

I'd be tempted to just sign out of your AppleID/iCloud account on the phone, restart it and sign back in. The iCloud servers think that you are not signed into something and signing out and back in might reset that flag.

If you suspect compromise, check your backups and erase the device. Don’t restore backup initially and test signing in with iCloud. Once you’re sure that’s working, you can erase again and restore backup.
That message is usually related to FaceTime or Messages, so you should make sure you have SMS from your carrier and then turn off iCloud for both, restart and the turn them on and see that they register.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/108791

